# Parsing partial XML created with SudzC in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, sudzc

Hello to all in this lovely community,

I am trying to get the contents of the data that is returned with a SudzC method from my web service. The webservice sends the data in a kind of partial XML like this:

```
<gUser>
 <user USERID="224" USERNAME="name" USERSURNAME="surname" PASSWORD="123" TELEPHONE="+123" EMAIL="" USERTYPE="2"></user>
</gUser>
```

This is returned as (id) in the SudzC method. It can be assigned to a dictionary, string and it can be printed with NSLog etc. However, I was not able to get what I need; the attributes of USERID, USERNAME and so on.

**EDIT**
The result is of type NSCFString. It contains the whole XML data I wrote above in one string object. I tried to call a parser method that takes an NSString* obj(in this case, the result) as parameter, it gives the *unrecognized selector* exception. How am I going to parse/use this data if I can't divide the whole into pieces.

How should I proceed? Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Besel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for `sudzc` each element returned has a method called `-attributes` that contains all of that element's attributes as an array of nodes.  You'll then have to iterate through that array to find the attributes you want.

Comment: Thanks. But the result I have at them moment is returned by the handler. `-(void)handleFind: (id) result { NSString *string = result;}` The _result_ doesnt have any attributes. Sorry I cant be as clear as I should. I am, as you can easily guess, new in this. Do I need to import some other classes than its main webservice class.

Comment: I solved my problem. Rewrote the parser and some more related to Core Data. That was really challenging for me. Nothing extraordinary of course, careful eyes, clear head. Still thanks.